# Rank of a Poisson structure is always even

Tags: manifolds, poisson-geometry

So I was reading a book on algebraic integrability. In the section about Poisson manifolds they say that the skew-symmetry of the Poisson matrix $X:=(\{x_i,x_j\})_{1\le i,j \le n}$ implies that the Rank of a Poisson structure at a point is always even. Can someone explain why that is? I tried to work it out but couldn't see it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone asking the same question:
A basic fact about skew-symmetric matrices is, that they have even rank. A proof of that can be found [here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=cyX32q8ZP5cC&lpg=PA12&dq=rank%20of%20skew-symmetric%20matrix&hl=de&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q=rank%20of%20skew-symmetric%20matrix&f=false).
The second fact is that the rank of the Poisson matrix is equal to the rank of the poisson structure at a point $m$. I couldn't find an explanation for that so I posted a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656068/rank-of-poisson-matrix-equals-rank-of-poisson-structure).
The result follows.